# Using Xsane with HP network scanner results in JPEG artifacts

Tags: xsane

I'm confused, I used Xsane for years with a USB MFP scanner. No problems! A bit dated and confusing multi window UI, but okay. Now for some reason I get PNG images with artifacts on this new printer/scanner and searching the Internet gives me no clear directions what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you selected PNG as a lossless format to save the scan, there is an advanced option —*Menu:* ***Show advanced options (Ctrl+6)***—where you can set the **compression** used for transmission from the scanner to the client from JPEG to **None**. You should see better results on higher resolutions now, I did.

[image]

<sub>I looked at [LP:192176](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/192176?comments=all) and spend to much time trying to understand what the different parties where talking about when the bug was apparently solved, but users are still experiencing this behavior by default.</sub>

<sub>Therefore I'm putting this answer here and hope people don't have to waste anymore time trying to edit files, updating packages, reading walls of text or else.</sub>

Edit 2022-04-02: New problems, not sure if they are related to running Wayland. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679321/resize-xsane-tiny-window-in-gnome Also, raising this in simple-scan: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/simple-scan/-/issues/294